# Data Binding in a Windows Phone project through a text file

Tags: c#, android, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime

I've recently been thinking App development after finishing up my third year project. I'd developed a decent contact management system w/cloud backup.

During the development, I'd realised how helpful XAML and specifically databinding is to developing UI. Two way binding a textbox, binding a listview to an observable collection... All very handy.

Anyway, the point to this question is that in my current app I'm developing for fun, I was looking to binding my UI elements to a file that is held by the app. The idea behind this is that- if the config file is set up correctly:

- colour, fonts and such can be swapped out easily, so if this was a business app, said business could have their own colours set up for the app (A Facebook employee logs in, the fonts and colours all set to the facebook blue- but if someone from say, Coca Cola logged into the system, the config file would set colour to red).
- Ideally, this file would be local- on first login the file is pulled from the server. The user logged in with a different system, the file would be replaced(would rather avoid the overhead of multiple files).

Anyway, would you stack exchange people have any idea on it?

What about using XML/JSON for the file containing the binding and having a model class hold the properties to bind to... I parse through the xml, bind to the single instance of the class(maybe set it up in a Singleton)?

I would love to do this on all three major mobile platforms(Android, iOS via Objective C and Windows Phone 8.1(C#)).

Anyway, just silly student talk...  Thanks guys 'n' gals.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind the UI element to a file directly.

Usually, you should bind the UI to the View Model (MVVM pattern).
The dynamic style is not a good example for the data binding, considering the performance of the traditional data binding, I recommended you using code behind to change the style dynamically.

How to change style dynamically: [how to change the font size of a grid's children text blocks dynamically in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483538/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-a-grids-children-text-blocks-dynamically-in-c/31528861#31528861)